# How to insert node by xpath in nodejs, typescript?

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath

I'm trying to make some code to insert node into generic config by xpath.
Usually I'm writing .Net applications but now I need to write tool on nodejs, type script
I don't get it how write it right
How to make cast of **childNodes[0]** so I can call **appendChild**?

```
import {DOMParser as dom} from "xmldom";
import * as xpath from "xpath";

export default class FileJob extends BaseJob {
    async execute(settings: JobSettings) {
            this.poke('C:\\Temp\\LocalCache\\Config.xml','/Root','<DB-Connection id="development" database="development"/>');
    }

    private poke(path:fs.PathLike,pathToNode:string, node : string)
    {
        const file = fs.readFileSync(path,'utf-8');
        var doc = new dom().parseFromString(file);
        var tempDoc = new dom().parseFromString(node);
        var importedNode = doc.importNode(tempDoc.documentElement, true);
        var childNodes = xpath.select(pathToNode, doc);
        if (childNodes[0]!==undefined)
        {
            //What to do here?
            //Property 'appendChild' does not exist on type 'SelectedValue'.
            //Property 'appendChild' does not exist on type 'string'.
            childNodes[0].appendChild(importedNode);
            fs.writeFileSync(path,doc.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupid and young.
Here is what was necessary.

```
import {DOMParser as dom} from "xmldom";
import * as xpath from "xpath";

export default class FileJob extends BaseJob {
    async execute(settings: JobSettings) {
            this.poke('C:\\Temp\\LocalCache\\Config.xml','/Root','<DB-Connection id="development" database="development"/>');
    }

    private poke(path:fs.PathLike,pathToNode:string, node : string)
    {
        const file = fs.readFileSync(path,'utf-8');
        var doc = new dom().parseFromString(file);
        var tempDoc = new dom().parseFromString(node);
        var importedNode = doc.importNode(tempDoc.documentElement, true);
        var childNodes = xpath.select(pathToNode, doc);
        if (childNodes[0]!==undefined)
        {
          let currentNode = childNodes[0] as Node;
          currentNode.appendChild(importedNode);
          fs.writeFileSync(path,doc.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tomalak Post it with my addition and I will accept it.

Comment: It not worked for because of compilation but you gave me a hint about type cast.
I already kept in mind this import stuff but not left it for the end.
After this I tried small fix and finally I get what I wanted,
I wanted right answer too much because I spent a couple of days for such simple feature.
Usually I using another tools\language and so on.
Thank you for your idea and sorry for my behavior.